# Two algebraic guises of Alternating Sign Matrices: any connection?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, bruhat-order

[Alternating Sign Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_sign_matrix) (ASMs) have a famous history: they were discovered by Mills, Robbins, and Rumsey, who conjectured a product formula for their enumeration; this product formula was first proved by Zeilberger via a very complicated inductive argument; then [Kuperberg](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9712207) gave a much more concise proof using a connection to statistical mechanics, specifically, the so-called "[six-vertex model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice-type_model)."

The six-vertex model is an exactly solvable model: it can be solved via a (quantum) Yang-Baxter equation. Although certainly this isn't how Baxter thought of it, this [Yang-Baxter equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Baxter_equation) could be thought of as coming from the R-matrix associated to (a particular module for) the [quantum group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group) $U_q(\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_2)$ (see e.g. [here](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/quantum/lecture6.pdf)). Thus in at least a tenuous sense ASMs "have to do with" the quantized enveloping algebra of the affine Lie algebra $\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_2$.

On the other hand, there is a completely different algebraic guise of the ASMs due to [Lascoux and Schützenberger](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v3i2r27): the ASMs naturally correspond to the elements of the [MacNeille completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion) of the (strong) [Bruhat order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_order) on the symmetric group. (As far as I know, this algebraic interpretation does not help in any way to count the ASMs.)

**Question**: is there any direct connection between these two parts of algebra in which ASMs "arise"? Is there any reason to think that the MacNeille completion of Bruhat order on $S_n$ would be related to $U_q(\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_2)$?